# VBScript Permission denied when I delete a file

Tags: vbscript

Let me start by saying I am self taught in VBScript.

I have a folder that gets filled with temporary files and I need to delete them.

So I created a script when it runs I am getting a permission denied when the script tries to delete the file.  I am a Domain Admin, but to be sure I manually deleted a file and had no issues.  I get the same message even when I run the script on the server.

I tried to post all of my code here put I had a hard time reading it.  If you can tell me how to post it so you can read it please let me know.  I saw something about putting a ">" on the first line put It was not putting everything on one line.

Here is the section I am having issues with, the error is the last line (Permission Denied)

> Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(strFolder1 & "\" & strFileName.Name)
>      objFSO.DeleteFile myFileToDelete, True

OK I looked at help more.  I could not indent even with 4 spaces in front. Not sure how to code this, I tried but I cannot get it to accept it.

TIA,
Rodger

Comment: to format code: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Can you post the entire code so I can try to recreate the problem? It could be problem with the code or something we can workaround in the code, lets single that out first.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you're asking:

```vb
Sub DeleteMyFile(myFileToDelete)
   Dim fso
   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   fso.DeleteFile(myFileToDelete)
End Sub

myFileToDelete = strFolder1 & "\" & strFileName
DeleteMyFile(myFileToDelete)
```